# SwiftUI Charts - no chart displayed

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

in a more complex chart that displays multiple charts I want to add text annotations to the maximum and minimum value with the value for clarity. To make the annotations easy to read, I want to add a background and a border. When I started working with the annotations, the chart disappeared.

Eventually I discovered a few bugs or ugly features in Charts.
The problem is in the `.overlay` position of the annotations.
When the annotation is just Text(), everything is OK and the chart is displayed.
When you append `.background` to the `Text()` annotation at the `.overlay` position, the chart does not display.

```
.annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) {
                    Text("\(hour.value)°")
                        .background(.yellow)
}
```

Full example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    struct Value: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var time: Date
        var value: Int
        
        var timeStr : String {
            "\(time)"
        }
    }
    
    let data = [
        Value(time: Date().startOfHour().adding(hours: 0), value: 7),
        Value(time: Date().startOfHour().adding(hours: 1), value: 9),
        Value(time: Date().startOfHour().adding(hours: 2), value: 12),
        Value(time: Date().startOfHour().adding(hours: 3), value: 16),
        Value(time: Date().startOfHour().adding(hours: 4), value: 6),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Chart (data) { hour in
            LineMark(x: .value("Day", hour.time), y: .value("Value", hour.value))
                .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
            PointMark(x: .value("Day", hour.time), y: .value("Value", hour.value))
                // step 1: change .top to .overlay and the graph disappears
                .annotation(position: .top, alignment: .center) {
                    Text("\(hour.value)°")
                    // step 2: comment out all text attributes and the graph will reappear
                        .font(.caption2)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 3)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                           )
                        .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                                    .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 1)
                            )
                    // step 2 end
                }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(height: 200)
    }

    
}

extension Date {
    func startOfHour() -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: self)
        
        components.minute = 0
        components.second = 0
        
        return calendar.date(from: components)!
    }
    
    func adding(hours: Int) -> Date {
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hours, to: self)!
    }

 }
```

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests (the chart is displayed). On MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15.1, tested on real ios17 devices (not Previews),
MacCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.

Comment: I can see in my tests, that the `Text` annotations are not displayed when using `.overlay`,
              but works for me with `.automatic`.

Comment: The example I gave here is working. To break it, you need to change `.top` to `.overlay` in the annotation.